# How to check randomly generated values contained in the variables are not listed in same manner for 10,000 times

Tags: javascript, arrays, metadata

I have a java function where I am writing following parameters randomly to a .json file

```
 const extraMetadata = () => ([
  {
    display_type: "boost_number",
    trait_type: "Stamina",
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
  },
  {
    display_type: "boost_number",
    trait_type: "Strength",
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
  },
  {
    display_type: "boost_number",
    trait_type: "Aggressiveness",
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
  },
  {
    display_type: "boost_number",
    trait_type: "IQ",
    vvalue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
  },
  {
    display_type: "boost_number",
    trait_type: "Bravery",
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
  },
  {
    display_type: "boost_number",
    trait_type: "Nerdy",
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
  },
  {
    display_type: "boost_number",
    trait_type: "Coolness",
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
  },
]);
```

I am printing these variable like 10,000 times in 10,000 .json files. Where each file will have below values printed randomly.

Results inside the .json file

[image]

How can I make sure these entire parameters are not printed the exact same way.

If one of the .json file contains below values then I don't want the next randomly generated .json file to contain the same values for parameters. In that case, if same values are found in the parameters then regenerate next random number until no matches are found.

In other words, i dont want any .json to contain exact same values for all variables

```
  "trait_type": "Stamina",
  "value": 19

  "trait_type": "Strength",
  "value": 47

  "trait_type": "Aggressiveness",
  "value": 35

  "trait_type": "IQ",
  "vvalue": 33


 "trait_type": "Bravery",
      "value": 23
 
"trait_type": "Nerdy",
      "value": 13
    
"trait_type": "Coolness",
      "value": 12
```

Below is the line which pushes the values to single .json file

```
  attributes: [...attributesList, ...extraMetadata(),],
```

Comment: From [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random): "The implementation selects the initial seed to the random number generation algorithm; it cannot be chosen or reset by the user." Because you can't affect the generation, the only way to make this happen would be to manually do this. Then after you do all of this, you have something that likely won't do anything at all. Even when it does something, would the user even notice? I doubt that.

Comment: but we can catch every numbers and log to an array right?/ from that array i want the check to happen

Comment: Please be more careful with your tags.  This is not Java code, and you are not asking about Visual Studio.